# Invalid use of group function when using extra

Tags: python, django

I have seen it is a django issue on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/ly3ykSVx0B8 but the solutions they suggested on a linked resource are a bit complicated for my level.

Basically,

```
class Records(models.Model):
    task=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    unitcost=models.IntegerField()
    totalapplied=models.IntegerField()
```

So, sample data is:

```
Installation 3   30
Moving       4   10
```

I basically want to return

```
Installation 90
Moving       40
```

For that, I turned to extra which works:

```
Records.object.extra(select={'total':'SUM(unitcost * totalapplied)'}).values('task','total')
```

The generated query groups on 'total' as well, generating a mysql query. Is there an easier work around that can be applied like a class instance or something since I have similar models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use F() expressions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

And annotate : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

```
Records.objects.annotate(total=Sum(F('unitcost') * F('totalapplied'))).values('task','total')
```

Tips, u can see your SQL Query like that :

```
 Records.objects.annotate(total=Sum(F('unitcost') * F('totalapplied'))).values('task','total').query.__str__()
```

Comment: Except SUM have to be Sum, it is perfect @Aurelien. Thanks a bunch.